# Get instance of ConsoleLineTracker

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've created an extension point for an `IConsoleLineTracker`, using the following in `plugin.xml`:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.consoleLineTrackers">
    <consoleLineTracker
        id="com.example.OutputSensor"
        class="com.example.OutputSensor"
        processType="java">
    </consoleLineTracker>
</extension>
```

The class `OutputSensor` implements `IConsoleLineTracker`. Each time the `lineAppended` method is called, I'm able to see the line that was added. I would like to store the lines being added in an *instance* of `OutputSensor` and get access to it from elsewhere in the plugin.

Is there some way I can access the instance of `OutputSensor` that was created by my plugin?  Currently I'm just using static variables in `OutputSensor`, but I would much rather use an instance of it, preferably a singleton.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general mechanism for getting classes created from extension point definitions.

I also can't see any public API to get the console line trackers that have been created.

So I think the best you can do is set a singleton variable in the constructor of your `OutputSensor`.

Comment: > There is no general mechanism...

Interesting. Is there some way to manually create the Sensor myself and point it at a particular process type? That way I would have access to the instance myself.

> singleton variable

Yes, seems like this is the way to go, in the absence of something better. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can see all the console line tracker code is in internal classes with no public API so there is no way to connect up any class you created yourself.